# Reverse Linked list giving wrong answer

Tags: java

I have the following code to reverse linked list
But I am getting NPE at
        head.next = prev;
How can I resolve it?

```
    ListNode l = new ListNode();
            l.insert(4);
            l.insert(10);
            l.insert(12);

            l.show();
            l.reverse();
            l.show();

public void reverse() {
        ListNode nextNode = null;
        ListNode curr = head;
        ListNode prev = null;

        while (curr != null) {

            nextNode = curr.next;
            curr.next = prev;
            prev = curr;
            curr = nextNode;
        }

        head = curr;
        head.next = prev;

    }
```

Comment: head = curr; is also done if curr is null. most likely, there's your problem (at least one)

Answer (score 0):

you're checking for `curr` to be null or not while you should check for `curr.next` to be null or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am on mobile but what I see in the first go is...

`head = curr;`  is out of while loop which means null will also be added to head and in next line

`head.next = prev;` we have an operation performed with 'dot'. That would lead to failure I feel.

is it the only issue??